# Парсить json не используя стандартных библиотек

Tags: c#, json

Здравствуйте, нужно парсить json не используя библиотек (кроме стандартных) на C#
Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы забыли поставить в конце знак вопроса: Нужно парсить ...? Ответ: нет, не нужно.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: У вас в заголовке вопроса «не используя стандартных библиотек», а в самом вопросе «не используя библиотек кроме стандартных». Вы уж определитесь, что именно вам надо.

Answer (score 1):

Встроенный в Net сериализатор и десериализатор Json

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
//Преобразовывает твой объект в JSON
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(объект);
//Производит обратную операцию предыдущему действию
object obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize("Json строка", Тип);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверю

Answer (score 0):

json это текст, в C# [есть что то типа](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) json_decode($var), на выходе получается объект, просто забери оттуда что тебе нужно, если там есть циклические данные, пропусти через цикл. В PHP я с результатом так поступаю. Но никто не мешает обработать текст и без библиотек, но нужно будет учесть формат полей и придумать собственный велосипед.
[Тут вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c) парсят уже но в английском варианте